# How do I copy files at same location ending with "*100000.prm" with different name "*full.prm" in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *1000000.wgt; do
    BASE=${FILE%1000000.wgt}
    [[ -e $BASE.trs && -e $BASE.1000000.wgt ]] && cp "$FILE" "$BASE.trs" "$BASE.wav" /some/dir
done
```

Comment: Please explain your problem.

Comment: You mean `cat *1000000.prm > ../asd/full.rpm` ?

Comment: I want to copy all files ending with 100000.prm . i.e "*100000.prm" to same location replacing '100000' with 'full'. Is there a way I can do it by command line?

Comment: eg: 'xyz_100000.prm' is to be copied with name 'xyz_full.prm' at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

This script does what you need according to your commment.

> eg: 'xyz_100000.prm' is to be copied with name 'xyz_full.prm' at the same location.

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=$'\n'

for FILE in *1000000.prm; do
    new_name=$(echo "$FILE" | sed "s/1000000.prm$/full.prm/")
    cp "$FILE" "$new_name"
done
```

Demonstration:

```
➜  ls
a1000000.prm  b1000000.prm  copy.sh
➜  ./copy.sh 
➜  ls
afull.prm  bfull.prm  copy.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
for i in *1000000.prm; do mv $i ${i%1000000.prm}full.prm; done
```

Read `Parameter expansion` section from `bash` man page.